# Disable Pairwise Master Key Caching

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi

I asked this question some time ago on another forum but never received an answer. I'm hoping that I may get a better answer here.

The wireless network at my university is a bit shaky and I was wondering if there is a way to disable Pairwise Master Key Caching under 2.3.3. This seems to have fixed the problem on my laptop. I am rooted and can edit configuration files if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which OS runs on your Laptop, but **Android uses the [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) for WiFi authentication.** If wpa_supplicant provides a way to disable the cache, you will have to configure it in the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Flow. My laptop is running Windows 7. I checked the wpa_supplicant on my phone and that network is currently set for PEAP. Should I try something else?